# WinDBG dt truncating long CString value

Tags: string, debugging, mfc, windbg

I'm debugging an application using WinDBG and looking up CString values using...

```
dt -a [memory address] CString
```

This works great, except when CString extremely long, such as for an XML structure written into a CString. After 8003 characters, WinDBG is truncating the rest and I'm not able to see anything further. Is there any way to prevent this or to dump out the entire CString value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague showed me the wonders of 'da'. Here is what I did to find the entire string:

```
> dt xmlString
Local var @ 0x12f328 Type ATL::CStringT<...
+0x000 m_pszData        : 0x09bad150  
> da 9bad150
09bad150  "<?xml version="1.0"?>..<?xml-sty"
09bad170  "lesheet type='text/xml' href='do"
...
> da 9bad2b0
09bad2b0 "string">..."
```

da dumped out the string in 32 byte increments, so I continued with 'da' through the addresses until I reached the end (or up to the point of the XML string I needed).